# as.character removes backticks from parsed script

Tags: r

I'm searching R scripts and not sure why `as.character()` drops the `` `[` ``. Is there some way to get the code back correctly as a vector of strings?

Notice the  `` `[`(. < 5) `` turns into `(. < 5)[]`

*Note: I'm not looking for better ways to make this call as this isn't my code.*

```r
code <- 
  "1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5) %>% mean()
   a <- 1:3"

# fine
parse(text = code)
#> expression(1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5) %>% mean(), a <- 1:3)

# not fine
as.character(parse(text = code))
#> [1] "1:10 %>% (. < 5)[] %>% mean()" 
#> [2] "a <- 1:3"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The issue is that I need to substitute out parts of the code so that my function works. The function finds reactive commands and changes them to functions for the user to access in their environment. It's part of my [shinyobjects](https://rjake.github.io/shinyobjects/) package (shameless plug).

```r
a <- reactive({
  input$n * 100
})
```

and converts it to

```r
a <- function() {
  input$n *100
}
```

The methods I have been using have been fine until this edge case with the `` `[` ``.

The solution should be able to return each expression as something I can manipulate. This is a more complex example and should return a string vector of length 5. I'm also happy to take this discussion offline as I'm open to a better method overall for this functionality. You can find my contact [here](https://github.com/rjake)

```r
code <- 
'library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5) %>% mean()

df <- reactive({
  mpg %>% 
  filter(cty > input$cty)
})

renderPlot(
  ggplot(df(), aes(class)) +
  geom_bar()
)'
```

Comment: What is your expected output.  Is it a vector of strings after converting to `as.chararacter`

Comment: Yes, a vector of strings. Thank you for attempting it.

Comment: So, what is it you really want/need to do?  If all you are trying to do is get rid of the ```  backticks, then use regex or `stringr::strsub` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the edit updates.  I still think you're trying to "duct-tape&string" a poorly-chosen solution method to the fundamental editing problem here.   Just grab the original input argument - or `formals` to the `reactive` call   and stuff the output into your new function "a"  via `body(a)`

Comment: I agree that the string method is not ideal. Unfortunately, the docs I've found don't speak to my use case. I'd like to understand the right way to do this (other than getting the `shiny` team to fix this upstream). Let's move our discussion arounnd better methods to this new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62697844/put-r-function-formals-into-new-function-body-from-code-as-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I've edited this a bit to explain the behaviour some more):

The problem is that `magrittr`'s pipe operator uses non-standard evaluation inconsistently.

The expression

```
`[`(. < 5)
```

is legal R code that is equivalent to what was deparsed:

```
 (. < 5)[]
```

However, it's a weird enough expression that `magrittr` gets confused by it, and doesn't transform

```
 1:10 %>% (. < 5)[]
```

the same way it would transform

```
 1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5)
```

I wouldn't call this a bug in `magrittr` (it's documented behaviour, if you look closely enough), but it's certainly an inconvenience caused by the inconsistent handling of dots.  Normally if you put a dot in a term in a `magrittr` chain, that's the *only* place that the previous result is put in.  For example, this doesn't print "foobar" twice:

```
"foobar" %>% cat("arg1", ., "arg3")
```

However, if the dot is in a function call in the chain, it is also inserted at the start:

```
"foobar" %>% cat("arg1", identity(.), "arg3")
```

*does* print it twice.

`magrittr` is evaluating `1:10 %>%` [`(. < 5)` as

```
`[`(1:10, 1:10 < 5)
```

i.e.

```
(1:10)[1:10 < 5]
```

Really for consistency it would require you to type

```
1:10 %>% `[`(., . < 5)
```

but it is trying to be helpful, which is what is so unhelpful for what you want to do.

I suppose you could write a function to detect these cases yourself, and insert the extra dot explicitly.

Edited to add:  Here's such a function:

```
explicitDots <- function(expr) {
  nestedDot <- function(lang) {
    if (is.call(lang)) {
      for (i in seq_along(lang)) {
        if (nestedDot(lang[[i]]))
          return(TRUE)
      }
      return(FALSE)
    } else 
      identical(lang, quote(.))
  }
  fixLang <- function(lang) {
    if (is.call(lang)) {
      fn <- lang[[1]]
      if (as.character(fn) == "%>%") {
        lang[[2]] <- fixLang(lang[[2]])
        lang[[3]] <- fixLang(lang[[3]])
      } else {
        hasTopLevelDot <- FALSE
        hasNestedDot <- FALSE
        for (i in seq_along(lang)[-1]) {
          if (identical(lang[[i]], quote(.))) {
            hasTopLevelDot <- TRUE
            break
          }
          hasNestedDot <- hasNestedDot || nestedDot(lang[[i]])
        }
        if (hasNestedDot && !hasTopLevelDot) {
          # Insert a dot in position 2
          lang <- lang[c(1,seq_along(lang))]
          lang[[2]] <- quote(.)
        }
      }
    }
    lang
  }
  expr <- removeSource(expr)
  for (i in seq_along(expr)) {
    expr[[i]] <- fixLang(expr[[i]])
  }
  expr
}
```

And here's an example using it:

```
code <- 
  "1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5) %>% mean()
   a <- 1:3"

p <- parse(text = code)
explicitDots(p)
```

which produced this output:

```
expression(1:10 %>% .[. < 5] %>% mean(), a <- 1:3)
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Any idea how to get around it with regards to capturing the code as-is and as a string?

Comment: I was editing some explanation as you were writing your comment.  The last line is new; that's the idea:  parse the expression, detect the special dot handling, insert the extra dot, then convert to characters.

Comment: Bravo! That is a great idea. I wish I had a better way to deal with the code but this will do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to get a vector of strings, one option is `strsplit` on the nextline character followed by zero or more spaces

```
out <- strsplit(code, "\n\\s*")[[1]]
out
#[1] "1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5) %>% mean()" 
#[2] "a <- 1:3" 

sapply(out, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
#$`1:10 %>% `[`(. < 5) %>% mean()`
#[1] 2.5

#$`a <- 1:3`
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Ooooh!   `eval(parse())` !   :-)

Comment: FWIW, if I wanted to make this into executable, I'd create  `foofunc <- function()` followed by `body(foofunc) <- out`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am not sure about OP's actual test case.  I agree in general that it is not good to have eval(parse

Comment: Thank you for this attempt. Unfortunately it doesn't work with multi-line code. I added a better example and more context in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be aware of the "never use `parse` " rule -- there are always better ways.

Next, what you get back is an `expression` , not an object which tells you **about** an expression.
Similarly, you're explicitly barred from trying to pull this trick with a closure:

```
bar <- as.character(function(x) x+3)
Error in as.character(function(x) x + 3) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Now,

```
foo <- parse(text = code)
as.character(deparse(foo))
[1] "structure(expression(1:10 %>% (. < 5)[] %>% mean(), a <- 1:3), srcfile = <environment>, wholeSrcref = structure(c(1L, "
[2] "0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L), srcfile = <environment>, class = \"srcref\"))"
```

Should give you a feel for what you're dealing with.

But it's not clear why you want/need to take a string, parse it, and then try to get it back again.  Either follow akrun's approach or take another route to turn poorly structured text into executable commands.

Comment: Thank you for this attempt. Unfortunately it doesn't work with multi-line code. I added a better example and more context in the question.