# Update/replace expressions

Tags: r

I want to swap out some code that a user has written. The expressions act like a list but I can't find out how to update them. I can `append()`, but not `replace()`.

```r
orig_code <-
  parse(text = 
    "library(tidyverse)   
    list_1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)"
  )

new_code <- parse(text = "list_1 <- list(a = 1:3)")


# I can append
append(
  x = orig_code,
  values = new_code
)
#> expression(
#>   library(tidyverse), 
#>   list_1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2), 
#>   list_1 <- list(a = 1:3)
#> )


# but not replace
replace(
  x = orig_code,
  list = 2,
  values = new_code
)
#> expression(
#>   library(tidyverse), 
#>   list_1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
#> )

# or reassign
orig_code[[2]] <- new_code

orig_code
#> expression(
#>   library(tidyverse), 
#>   list_1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
#> )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is strange, note that the documents of replace says that your passed in variable will remain unchanged you have to reassign it, but even after reassignement it still prints `orig_code`. But if I evaluate that expression a list is created with new values, using `eval(replace(x=orig_code, list=2, values=new_code)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An option is to convert it to `list`, then do the `replace`ment, and change it to `expression`

```
as.expression(c(replace(
   x = as.list(orig_code),
  list = 2,
   values = as.list(new_code
    ))))
#expression(library(tidyverse), list_1 <- list(a = 1:3))
```

Comment: Do you think you could take a crack at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62697844/apply-map-r-function-formals-into-new-function-body-from-code-as-string